# How to use shiny inputpael to filter my dataframe by a category in a column? Rshiny and RMarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, dt, rshiny

I'm trying to make a simple shiny app where I can select an input of cylinders(4,6, or 8) and then generate a table with the cars who are either 4,6, or 8 cylinders.

This is my code

````
---
title: "Test Dash"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny
  
---

  Inputs {.sidebar data-width=300}
=====================================
  
$$\\[.01in]$$
  
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, out.width = '100%'}
library(readr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

```


```{r}

cylinder <- mtcars$cyl

selectInput("my_dropdown", label = "Select Cylinders:", choices = cylinder)

```

# Overview

Column {data-width=750}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Table
  
```{r}
renderDataTable(
  datatable(mtcars[input$my_dropdown,]
  )  
)

```
````

i'm able to generate the input and an empty table but the table does not update when I choose a cylinder.
Here is a screenshot.

Any idea how I can fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
mtcars2 <- reactive({
    mtcars[mtcars$cyl == input$my_dropdown,]
})

renderDataTable(
  datatable(mtcars2())
  )  
)
```

Comment: Why does this solve the problem? Can you edit your answer to include an explanation?